# Discord API Error on Deleting a Text Channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been getting an error as mentioned in the title. Whenever I use that command, the bot creates a channel that brings up a select menu, through which the user can "teleport" to another channel while deleting the newly created channel in the process. This code successfully works twice, after which it gives the error. What should be done to fix the error so that the user can use the command as many times as they'd like? I'll work on this code further once the solution is found, but until then, I'm really stumped here. (Questions shall be answered upon questioning; apologies for the messy coding)

```js
module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('855845132879921214')
   const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('959851265456734319')
  const newChannel = await msg.guild.channels.create(`teleporter`)
  await newChannel.permissionOverwrites.edit(msg.author.id,  {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
      })
  const {MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Teleporter!`)
  .setDescription("Through this interaction, you can now teleport to the main channel of the desired category!")
  const row = new MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(
    new MessageSelectMenu()
    .setCustomId('teleport')
    .setPlaceholder('Choose a channel')
    .addOptions([
      {
        label: 'Rules',
        description: "Click to check the rules",
        value: 'rules',
      },
  {
    label: 'General',
    description: "Click to go to the main chat",
    value: 'general',
  },
      {
      label: 'Media',
      description: "Click to go to media channel",
      value: 'media',
      },
      {
        label: 'Bots',
        description: "Click to go to the bots channel",
        value: 'bots',
      }
    ]),
  )
  await newChannel.send({content: `<@${msg.author.id}>`,embeds: [embed], components: [row]})
  const wait = require('util').promisify
  client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch({
      user: interaction.user.id,
      force: true
    })
    if(!interaction.isSelectMenu()) { 
      interaction.deferUpdate()}
    else if (interaction.values == 'general'){ 
      msg.member.roles.add('958421069650337822')
      msg.member.roles.remove('943159431800172584')
      let tele = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == 'teleporter')
    tele.delete()
    msg.member.roles.add('943159431800172584')
    msg.member.roles.remove('958421069650337822')
    }
  }
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't cache.find and delete, do it like;

```js
const newChannel = await client.channels.fetch("id")
newChannel.delete()
```

Comment: await client.channels.delete is not a function. I replaced the 'let tele' and 'tele.delete' lines with await client.channels.delete('teleporter') AND await client.channels.delete(newChannel) but got that error. The code worked until i clicked 'general' in the select menu.

Comment: Did you try with id?

Comment: Edited post....

Comment: The channel is created whenever the command is used, thus giving each new creation a unique id. Which is why I cannot type a single id in that line as it would not work for every new iteration of that channel. For example:
ID of channel created first time: 972850512049352724
ID of channel created second time: 972850594882682910
EDIT: just noticed your edit, gonna try that

Comment: Okay type channel variable into "id" place without quotes.

Comment: await client.channels.fetch('teleporter') AND await client.channels.fetch(newChannel) give a discord api error saying "invalid form body"

Comment: Dude, did it: await client.channels.fetch(tele.id)

Comment: because you defined teleporter channel as tele.

Comment: Can you provide the coded parts? It is hard for me to figure where you applied the code or are insisting to apply the code (Like which line should I edit) P.S: I dont have rep to take this into chat but kindly drop your discord tag to continue this discussion if needed. Thanks

Comment: I'm not on PC. Just delete "tele.delete()" line and paste my post code. Type tele.id which is your channel variable without quotes into id place.

Comment: let tele = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == 'teleporter')
    const newChannel = await client.channels.fetch(tele.id)
newChannel.delete()

No luck: still runs twice.

Comment: What error did you get after run this code?

Comment: The same "Discord API Error: Unknown Channel" error

Comment: Which line it's showing on error?

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Treant-Protestor/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/Treant-Protestor/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/972855635051941898',
  code: 10003,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}

Comment: There should be more lines, this is not showing error line. Copy full.

Comment: FYI this is the console log above the error i posted (The arrow is under 'new'): /home/runner/Treant-Protestor/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

Comment: One important factor I should mention is that I have coded this on replit, an online IDE, not any coding software.

Comment: Let me try this. I'll write here if you didn't find solution.

Comment: Sure, i'll be waiting

Answer (score 0):

This code should be separated with the first section as your command and the second part as a separate listener, so I have coded as such.

```js
const {
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageSelectMenu,
    MessageEmbed,
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('855845132879921214');
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('959851265456734319');
    const newChannel = await msg.guild.channels.create(`teleporter-${msg.author.username}`, {
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: guild.id,
            deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        }, {
            id: msg.author,
            deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
            allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        }],
    });
    // In the event that more than one person uses this command at once, you will need to be able to tell the difference when you look up the channel later. So I added the username to the channel name.

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Teleporter!`)
        .setDescription("Through this interaction, you can now teleport to the main channel of the desired category!");
    const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageSelectMenu()
                .setCustomId('teleport')
                .setPlaceholder('Choose a channel')
                .addOptions([{
                    label: 'Rules',
                    description: "Click to check the rules",
                    value: 'rules',
                }, {
                    label: 'General',
                    description: "Click to go to the main chat",
                    value: 'general',
                }, {
                    label: 'Media',
                    description: "Click to go to media channel",
                    value: 'media',
                }, {
                    label: 'Bots',
                    description: "Click to go to the bots channel",
                    value: 'bots',
                }]),
        );
    await newChannel.send({
        content: `${msg.author}`,
        embeds: [embed],
        components: [row],
    });
};
```

This section would go either in the main bot.js file, or if you have your events in separate files, it would go in the `interactionCreate` file (may need to be changed a bit if you don't have one, let me know)

```js
const wait = require('util').promisify;
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    const member = interaction.member;
    const guild = interaction.guild;

    if (interaction.isSelectMenu()) {
        const menuName = interaction.customId;
        interaction.deferUpdate();
        if (menuName === 'teleport') {
            const tele = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == `teleporter-${member.user.username}`);
            // lookup the channel using the previously mentioned channel name setup
            const choice = interaction.value;
            if (choice === 'general') {
                member.roles.add('958421069650337822');
                member.roles.remove('943159431800172584');
            } else if (choice === 'rules') {
                member.roles.add('roleID');
                member.roles.remove('roleID');
            } else if (choice === 'media') {
                member.roles.add('roleID');
                member.roles.remove('roleID');
            } else if (choice === 'bots') {
                member.roles.add('roleID');
                member.roles.remove('roleID');
            }
            tele.delete();
        }
    }
});
```